# Chaining function not work when inside another function

Tags: javascript

I try to create chaining function using vanilla javascript, its work if just chaining, but if inside other function its stop working.

```
var doc = document,
M$ = function(el) {
  var expr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/;
  var m = expr.exec(el);
  if(m[1]) {
    return doc.getElementById(m[1]);
  } else if(m[2]) {
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(m[2]);
  } else if(m[3]) {
    return doc.getElementsByClassName(m[3]);
  }
},
$ = function (el) {
  this.el = M$(el);

  // event function
  this.event = function(type,fn) {
    this.el.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    return this;
  }

  // forEach function
  this.forEach = function(fn,val) {
    for(var i = this.el.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      fn.call(val, i, this.el[i]);
    }
    return this;
  }

  if(this instanceof $) {
    return this.$;
  } else {
    return new $(el);
  }
};

//use
$("button").forEach(function(index, el) 
 // when i use function event, its not work
  el.event("click", function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
  // if i'm using addEventListener its work, but i want use event function
});
```

My question is, how to be event function working inside forEach function?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is an issue with brackets in your code after `$("button").forEach(function(index, el)` you are missing `{`;

Then the problem is that when you try to call click-callback on your elements (buttons), in fact, due to the `this` issues the elements (buttons) don't have `event()` property. They are not even defined themselves since `this.el = M$(el);` goes outside `forEach()`. I tweaked and cleaned a little your code, check it out. I guess now it does what you want:

```js
var doc = document,
M$ = function(el) { 
  var expr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/;
  var m = expr.exec(el);
  if(m[1]) return doc.getElementById(m[1]); else if(m[2]) return doc.getElementsByTagName(m[2]); else if(m[3]) return doc.getElementsByClassName(m[3]);
}, 
$ = function(el) { 
  this.forEach = function(fn,val) {  
  // assign this.el and this.el[i].event inside forEach(), not outside  
    this.el = M$(el);
    for(var i = this.el.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.el[i].event = function(type,fn) { this.addEventListener(type,fn,false); };
        fn.call(val, i, this.el[i]);
    }
  }
  return this;
};
$("button").forEach(function(index, el) {
    el.event("click", function() { alert("hello, " + this.textContent); });
});
```

```html
<button>btn1</button>
<button>btn2</button>
```

**UPDATE**

While the previous solution is fine for the particular purpose of setting click handlers on buttons, I think what you really want is to emulate Jquery and chain function calls. I improved your attempt right in this way:

```js
var doc = document,
M$ = function(el) {
  var expr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/;
  var m = expr.exec(el);
  if(m[1]) return doc.getElementById(m[1]);else if(m[2]) return doc.getElementsByTagName(m[2]); else if(m[3]) return doc.getElementsByClassName(m[3]);
},
$ = function (el) { //console.log(this);
  this.el = M$(el);
  this.event = function(type,fn) {
    for(var i = this.el.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) this.el[i].addEventListener(type,fn,false);
  }
  this.forEach = function(fn) { 
      fn.call(this);
  }
  return this;
};

$("button").forEach(function() {
  this.event("click", function() {
    alert("hello, " + this.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<button>btn1</button>
<button>btn2</button>
```

The key to understanding here is that your `this` object should always be equal to `$ {el: HTMLCollection(2), event: function, forEach: function}`. So,

- calling `$("button")` you initially set it to `$ {el: HTMLCollection(2), event: function, forEach: function}` - with HTML Collection and event&forEach functions;
- calling `$("button").forEach(fn)` you keep `forEach`'s context equal to `this` from previous step;
- calling `fn.call(this);` inside `forEach()` you call your callback `fn` and pass the same `this` to it;
- inside the callback `fn` you call `this.event()` - it works because your `this` is always the one from the first step.
- in `this.event()` which is just `$.event()` we just traverse our HTMLCollection and set handlers for click event on buttons. Inside `$.event()` `this` will be equal to a button element because we call it in such a context on click event, so, `this.textContent` takes the buttons' content.

Thanks, really good question!

Comment: Thanks Its better solution. Ya! I want create function chaining like jquery but i dont want use huge library for small task and i like plain javascript.

I'm not expert on javascript, i'm still confuse for chaining function :D.. Thanks for help, its very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

1.

```
this.el = M$(el); 

M$ = function(el) {
  var expr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/;
  var m = expr.exec(el);
  if(m[1]) {
    return doc.getElementById(m[1]);
  } else if(m[2]) {
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(m[2]);
  } else if(m[3]) {
    return doc.getElementsByClassName(m[3]);
  }
}
```

As you defined M$ you can either have a [HtmlCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) if you get elements by tag name or by class name or just one element if you get element by id.

Then you suppose that your el is one when it can be a collection.

```
this.event = function(type,fn) {
    this.el.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    return this;
  }
```

You probably receive a collection if you try to get all buttons.

2.

If you try to run posted code you will receive an Unexpected identifier error because you missed a { after `forEach(function(index, el)`.

3.

If you put that { in there you will receive a `el.event` is not a function error because you don't have an event function on `el`, but you have that on `$(el)`.

4.

If you change your code to:

```
$("button").forEach(function(index, el)
{
 // when i use function event, its not work
  $(el).event("click", function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
  // if i'm using addEventListener its work, but i want use event function
});
```

You'll receive an error because you didn't handled multiple elements. See 1 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

```
var doc = document,
M$ = function(el) {
  var expr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/;
  var m = expr.exec(el);
  if(m[1]) {
    return Array.apply([],[doc.getElementById(m[1])]);
  } else if(m[2]) {
    return Array.apply([],doc.getElementsByTagName(m[2]));
  } else if(m[3]) {
    return Array.apply([],doc.getElementsByClassName(m[3]));
  }
},
$ = function (el) {
  if(! (this instanceof $)) {
    return new $(el);
  }
  this.els = M$(el);

  // event function
  this.event = function(type,fn) {
    this.forEach(function(index, el){
      el.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    });
    return this;
  }

  // forEach function
  this.forEach = function(fn,val) {
    for(var i = this.els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      fn.call(val, i, this.els[i]);
    }
    return this;
  }
  return this;
};

//use
$("button").event("click", function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

- Here the `M$ function` is made to return an array to keep things consistent.
- So, the `$().event` function is changed to iterate through all the elements in `this.els`.
- Hence, you could simply call `$("button").event` function instead of `$("button").forEach` function to register event listeners.

Refer: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhcz9haj/13/)
This one works. But, Is this what you want? I am not sure.